# SDHC not mounting

Tags: mount, sd-card

I have  a 16GB SDHC i card from transcend and nothing happens when I put it into the embedded sd card reader. I ran dmesg and got:

```
[   12.005989] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware cmd interrupt.
[   12.005998] sdhci: =========== REGISTER DUMP (mmc0)===========
[   12.006044] sdhci: Sys addr: 0x00000000 | Version:  0x00001502
[   12.006062] sdhci: Blk size: 0x00000000 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
[   12.006067] sdhci: Argument: 0x80000c08 | Trn mode: 0x00000000
[   12.006073] sdhci: Present:  0x1ef70001 | Host ctl: 0x00000001
[   12.006079] sdhci: Power:    0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[   12.006084] sdhci: Wake-up:  0x00000000 | Clock:    0x0000fa07
[   12.006089] sdhci: Timeout:  0x00000000 | Int stat: 0x00000000
[   12.006095] sdhci: Int enab: 0x00ff0083 | Sig enab: 0x00ff0083
[   12.006099] sdhci: AC12 err: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
[   12.006105] sdhci: Caps:     0x176ec8b0 | Caps_1:   0x03002177
[   12.006111] sdhci: Cmd:      0x0000341a | Max curr: 0x00000000
[   12.006114] sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x00000000
[   12.006130] sdhci: ADMA Err: 0x00000000 | ADMA Ptr: 0x0000000000000000
[   12.006131] sdhci: ===========================================
```

Thats all that comes up regarding the sd card.
It worked once before but its not working now.
I have looked through other forums and found people that have the same problem but their solutions didn't work for me.
Im on ubuntu 16.04 any help would be great.

Comment: Do other SD cards work as expected? please [edit] your post to include both this detail and the output of `lsusb` Thank you for helping us help you!